# Ejb injection null pointer

Tags: java, xml, ejb, websphere, code-injection

I have a websphere application server for my project in RAD and i am treying to inject objects with ejb.Here are my files

LoginServlet

```
@WebServlet("/login")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {  

    @EJB UserService userService;

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
            throws ServletException, IOException {  

        response.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

        String username=request.getParameter("username");  
        String password=request.getParameter("password");  

        String a = userService.authorize(username, password);

            if(username.equals("qwe"))
            {  
                RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("servlet2");  
                rd.forward(request, response);  
            }  
            else
            {  
                out.print("Sorry UserName or Password Error!");  
                RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");  
                rd.include(request, response);  

            }  
        }  

    }
```

UserService (also tried @ejb instead of @Inject for the dao)

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors(ApplicationEntityManagerInterceptor.class)
public class UserService{

    @Inject 
    protected UserDAO userDAO;


    public String authorize(String username,String password)
    {
        return this.userDAO.authenticate(username, password);   
    }

}
```

UserDAO

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors(ApplicationEntityManagerInterceptor.class)
public class UserDAO extends GenericDAOJpaImpl<User, String>
{

    public String authenticate(String username,String password)
    {
         Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         params.put("username", username);
         params.put("password", password);          
         User user= findSingleByNamedQueryAndNamedParams(User.AUTHENTICATE, params);
         return "TRUE";
    }

}
```

The interceptor

```
public class ApplicationEntityManagerInterceptor
{
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object joinTransaction(InvocationContext context) throws Exception
    {
        Object emAux = context.getParameters()[0];
        if(emAux instanceof EntityManager){
        EntityManager em = (EntityManager) emAux;
        em.joinTransaction();
        }
        return context.proceed();
    }

}
```

And inside web.xml

```
<ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>gr.mess.web.servlets.LoginServlet/userService</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
    <local>gr.mess.services.UserService</local>
    <injection-target>
        <injection-target-class>gr.mess.web.servlets.LoginServlet</injection-target-class>
        <injection-target-name>userService</injection-target-name>
    </injection-target>
</ejb-local-ref>
```

My problem is that the userService is created normaly but the DAO object inside the service is null.What should i do.I created this based on another project but that project works normally and i dont get it.In the other project the DAO is not any xml for any kind of configuration

UPDATE the GenericDAOJpaImpl
    @Stateless
    @Interceptors(ApplicationEntityManagerInterceptor.class)
    public class GenericDAOJpaImpl 
    {

```
protected Class<T> entityClass;

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "TEST_SQL")
protected EntityManager em;

public GenericDAOJpaImpl() {
    ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass()
         .getGenericSuperclass();
    this.entityClass = (Class<T>) genericSuperclass
         .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}

public T create(T t) ..
public T load(PK id) ..
public T update(T t)..
public void delete(T t) ..
public T save(T t) ..
public Class<T> getEntityClass()..
public Query createNamedQuery(String name)..
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")..
public List<T> findByNamedQuery(final String name, Object... params)..
public T findSingleByNamedQuery(final String name, Object... params)..
public List<T> findByNamedQueryAndNamedParams(final String name, final Map<String, ? extends Object> params)..
..
```

Update 2:
I fixed my problem by doing the following
creating a META-INF folder on the ear this time and adding three xml files named application.xml beans.xml and ibm-application-bnd.xml and adding the @Inject annontation above the userDAO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using CDI injection here.
- what version of `CDI`/`JEE`/`WebSphere` are you using here?
- Do you have a `beans.xml` file in `META-INF` of the jar or is CDI scanning implict (Depends on WAS/CDI version and setup) ?
- Does `"UserDAO"`qualifies as a CDI bean (ie what is the `GenericDAOJpaImpl`class?

You could add some tracing info in a method annoted with `@PostConctruct` in `UserDAO` to see if it is created by the CDI container

Comment: Websphere 8.0.0.9 ,Rad Version: 8.0.4.3 , Java jdk 1.6. No i dont have a beans.xml.I will add the implemantation of GenericDAOJpaImpl on my question. I will try with @PostConstruct and i will write here the result

Comment: I tested it and it is not created at all

Comment: you **need** an "empty" `beans.xml` file in `META-INF`for the CDI container to scan the jar and discover your CDI beans. You can find one here :https://gist.github.com/hgbrown/5128015. Also your `UserDAO`class **needs** an empty constructor to qualify as a CDI bean, that is not the case here, so the injection will not work

Comment: Still not working.Is it a problem what i have a maven based structure of folders src/main/webapp? Also i dont know if it helps somehow my error message is Error 500: javax.ejb.EJBException: com.ibm.websphere.csi.FaultException: acac0002000101180000004d455353454152234d4553532e776172235573657244414f

Comment: Everything is in the stack trace...Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class incompatible with java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
    at gr.mess.dao.GenericDAOJpaImpl.<init>(GenericDAOJpaImpl.java:31). This has nothing to do with WAS nor EJB, but the way you try to get the class of a generic class (T)..

Comment: Yeah i know i just made an update to say how i passed the problem.Now its a different problem i guess my question was answered.Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Glad you found a solution to your problem. If you consider that it answered your question, please "accept" the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if WebSphere is aware of injection specified in an EJB, and that injection cannot be satisfied, then the EJB itself will not be created. Since it sounds like the EJB is being created, then WebSphere is unaware of the UserDAO injection.  I would look for the following:

- web.xml version >= 2.5 (annotations ignored in older)
- ejb-jar.xml version >= 3.0 (annotations ignored in older)
- metadata-complete="false" or not set (true will ignore annotations)
- metadata-coplete set to "true" during install (an install option)

Comment: web.xml     <?xml version="1.0"  ....  ejb-jar.xml <?xml version="1.0"   But the other project doesnt use these xml for the Dependency injection

Comment: Also checked about the metadata and are set to false.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by doing the following creating a META-INF folder on the ear this time and adding three xml files named application.xml beans.xml and ibm-application-bnd.xml and adding the @Inject annontation above the userDAO

Comment: while there are annotations, It is better to use only annotation, is there any other option avoiding xml?